# Fit decision boundary to logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to plot a decision boundary in R using ggplot.

I have 2 variables (exam scores) and a binary classification whether a student was admitted to school or not.  The data looks like below:

```
> head(exam.data)
  Exam1Score Exam2Score Admitted
1   34.62366   78.02469        0
2   30.28671   43.89500        0
3   35.84741   72.90220        0
4   60.18260   86.30855        1
5   79.03274   75.34438        1
6   45.08328   56.31637        0
```

I can plot the data using ggplot:

```
exam.plot <- ggplot(data=exam.data, aes(x=Exam1Score, y=Exam2Score, col = ifelse(Admitted == 1,'dark green','red'), size=0.5))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x="Exam 1 Scores", y="Exam 2 Scores", title="Exam Scores", colour="Exam Scores")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

and then successfully fit the logistic regression model:

```
exam.lm <- glm(data=exam.data, formula=Admitted ~ Exam1Score + Exam2Score, family="binomial")
```

So after much searching the web, I decided to manually fit the decision boundary (though did try for a while doing this using stat_smooth but couldn't get it to work), I tried the following:

```
# Fit the decision boundary
plot_x <- c(min(exam.data$Exam1Score)-2, max(exam.data$Exam1Score)+2)
plot_y <- (-1 /coef(exam.lm)[3]) * (coef(exam.lm)[2] * plot_x + coef(exam.lm)[1])
db.data <- data.frame(rbind(plot_x, plot_y))
colnames(db.data) <- c('x','y')

# Add the decision boundary plot
ggplot()+geom_line(data=db.data, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

which successfully plots the decision boundary, but I can't add it to my existing plot with:

```
> exam.plot+geom_line(data=db.data, aes(x=x, y=y))
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:x, y
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong or whether I can actually do this with +stat_smooth()?

All code (ex2.R) and files are here: https://github.com/StuHorsman/rscripts/tree/master/R/Coursera

Thanks!

Stuart

Update: I can achieve some similar with:

```
plot(exam.data$Exam1Score, exam.data$Exam2Score, type="n", xlab="Exam 1 Scores", ylab="Exam 2 Scores")      
points(exam.data$Exam1Score[exam.data$Admitted==1], exam.data$Exam2Score[exam.data$Admitted==1], pch=4, col="green")  
points(exam.data$Exam1Score[exam.data$Admitted==0], exam.data$Exam2Score[exam.data$Admitted==0], pch=4, col="red")        
lines(db.data, col="blue")
```

Comment: Try using `geom_segment` instead of `geom_line`.  If you make your example reproducible (i.e contained data I could use, rather than just a sample), I may try to post a solution.

Comment: Hey Andrie, I posted all the code and dataset to github, the link is above.  Thanks for the tip I'll look at geom_segment.

Comment: I notice you tagged the script as Coursera.  What does your course code of honour say about posting code online?  Some other Coursera courses expressly prohibit this.

Comment: The code is my own code, nothing to do with the Coursera course or is a solution, I'm doing some of the exercises in R which is not a requirement for the course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `exam.plot` you use not only aesthetics `x` and `y`, but also `col` and `size` (the latter unnecesarily). The layers need to have *all* aesthetics set that are defined in the `ggplot ()` call. (I've been caught often by that problem).

Thus:

```
exam.plot+geom_line(data=db.data, aes(x=x, y=y), col = "black", size = 1)
```

does plot.

However, I'd recommend changing `exam.plot` a bit and removing all aesthetics that do not apply for all layers (and put them into the layer definition instead):

```
exam.plot <- ggplot(data=exam.data, aes(x = Exam1Score, y=Exam2Score))+
  geom_point(aes (col = Admitted), size = 0.5)+
  scale_color_manual (values =  c('red', 'dark green')) + 
  labs(x="Exam 1 Scores", y="Exam 2 Scores", title="Exam Scores", colour="Exam Scores")+
  theme_bw()+
  coord_equal () +  # assuming that the scores have the same scale.
  theme(legend.position="none")

exam.plot + geom_line(data=db.data, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

Which with example data

```
exam.data <- data.frame (Exam1Score = rnorm (100) + 0:1, 
                         Exam2Score = rnorm (100) + 0:1, 
                         Admitted = factor (rep (0:1, 50)))
```

yields:
[image: example plot]

(plotted with default size, 0.5 would hardly be visible for this example)

Comment: Awesome!  Many thanks.  I was confused on where to set aes but not anymore.  stu.

Answer (score 0):

Why not stat_function?

```
g=ggplot(exam.data,aes(x=Exam1score,y=Exam2score,col=factor(Admitted)))
g=g+geom_point(size=2.2)+scale_color_discrete(name="Administered")
g=g+stat_function(fun=function(x){(-Intercept-Beta1*x)/Beta2},xlim=c(0,100))
g
```

Intercept,beta1,beta2 are parameters of the logistic regression function.