# How to plot a decision boundary of logistic regression - RStudio

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression

I am implementing a logistic regression in R using HR Analytics data (predicting probability to leave the company: "leave" = 1 if true, 0 otherwise, based on two features.

For my final model, I have weights and the training data. There are 2 features, so my weight is vector with 2 rows.

How do i plot the decision boundary? I did search the net but couldn't find a solution so far.

```
### Load data
HR = read.csv(file = "HR_comma_sep.csv",header = TRUE, na.strings=c(""))
HR.2 <- HR[c("satisfaction_level","time_spend_company","left")]
###  Split the data "HR.2" into training and testing data
data <- HR.2 [1:12000,]
test.data <- HR.2 [12001:14999,]
### Fit a logistic regression model using training data
model <- glm (left ~ satisfaction_level + time_spend_company, 
         family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = data)
summary(model)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This answer might be useful https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6207/122730

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006741/fit-decision-boundary-to-logistic-regression-model-in-r , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015518/manually-plotting-straight-boundary-line-in-perceptron/38015736#38015736

Comment: Thanks a lot  @user20650, it actually worked :) with the first slution proposed.

Comment: I will stick to the first solution thanks @user20650 . Now I struggle including a legend ... currently it only shows "0" and "1" since my data is binomial and I would like to show the symbols with text "Left" & "Remained" .  The following code does not work: 
legend(x=0.8, y=10, 
       c("Left","Stayed")
       legend = levels(as.factor(HR.2$left)), 
       col = as.factor(HR.2$left), 
       pch = 20, 
       bty = "o", 
       pt.cex = 2, 
       cex = 1.2, 
       text.col=seq_along(levels(factor(HR.2$left))), 
       horiz = F)

Any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: If you are using the answer from the first link, then it uses ggplot / grid graphics so the function `legend` will not work. Try adding labels to the `scale_` line of code ie `scale_color_manual (values =  c('red', 'dark green'), labels = c("left", "right"))` , and remove  the `theme(legend.position="none")` line